# Angular adding PWA causing problem with Angular Ivy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.0.4
Node: 12.18.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
... service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.4
@angular/cli                      10.0.4
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.4
@schematics/angular               10.0.4
@schematics/update                0.1000.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

I added `ng add @angular/pwa` to project.

And this line:

```
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
```

In `app.module.ts` is causing problem:

```
    ERROR in node_modules/@angular/service-worker/service-worker.d.ts:15:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
    
    This likely means that the library (@angular/service-worker) which declares ServiceWorkerModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
    
    15 export declare class ServiceWorkerModule {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I resolve that problem?

It is hard to add more details to overcome stackoverflow parser, while I added many details using angular version command.

Comment: can you post your tsconfig.json please

Comment: It is default: https://github.com/gkucmierz/bitcoin-average/blob/master/tsconfig.json
https://github.com/gkucmierz/bitcoin-average/blob/master/tsconfig.app.json
https://github.com/gkucmierz/bitcoin-average/blob/master/tsconfig.base.json

Comment: you can clean your cache with npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 2):

you could set [enableIvy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) to false in your tsconfig.app.json, that should fix your problem

```
"enableIvy": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that helped

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```